# one of my badge vanished

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

Yesterday I asked my fifth question. Today when checking my profile I was told I got the badge "curious". I clicked ok and to track the next one, but the badge is not showing among the ones I got nor among the ones to track.

What do I do?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not a moderator, but I have seen that you have no [curious badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19975/silvercookies?tab=badges), which is confirmed by the [list of users with the badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/curious). But you should get it as you have 5 questions, upvoted all asked on different days...

Comment: You achieved this badge only a short time ago - so this might be a caching problem. Try and wait another day or two to see if it appears.

Comment: A caching problem since yesterday... is a long caching problem! Note that [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/curious?userid=19975) claims that you haven't received it yet.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin your link claimes he just got it (4 seconds ago). Seems like whatever it was, it has been updated.

Comment: @T3H40 You are right. Next time it happens I will wait one day or two

Answer (score 8):

You have [just been awarded](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/curious?userid=19975) with your curious badge.

Seems like in conclusion you do not only have to be curious, but a little patient as well as it can sometimes take a bit until badges are awarded/updated.

This has obvious performance reasons, as stated [here on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/time-before-badge-is-awarded).

More detail can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded):

> Other badges (mostly the ones which can only be awarded once, like the specialist badges) are awarded by a background process which appears to run only once a day. According to TheTXI (comment below), this seems to happen at 0:00 UTC (at least on meta), but since we don't have an official word on this, it's hard to say whether it's the same for all sites or is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I see you should qualify for the badge:

- You have a positive question record.
- You have 5 upvoted questions
- They were all asked on different days.

And yet you don't have it.

If you ask another question or get a few more upvotes that may trigger it to get past whatever the hitch is. Maybe you aren't quite upvoted enough somewhere or something similar.